# WCF IIS Error 403

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I am reading the book WCF 4.0 Multi-tier Services Development and tried implementing a simple Hello World with WCF using IIS.

I have a HelloWorldService project and a HostDevServer project (Startup Project). I should see a directory listening with two files but instead I get the next error message:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Most likely causes:

```
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

What I have done:

- Enabled Directory Browsing in IIS manager
- Checked if I had Default Documents, they were present.
- Run command: appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true

In the about screen in IIS it says version 7.5 and in the browser it says "IIS 8.0 Detailed error ...". I don't know if this has something to do with the problem.

I use Visual Studio 2013 for development. Web.config below:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post a web.config?

Comment: Updated the post with web.config.

Comment: My usual suspect is the permissions on the folder where your service is residing. Ensure that IUSR and/or (i never remember which) IIS_IUSRS have read permissions to your web service folder on your harddrive. Or, if your appPool is running on a different set of credentials do the same with this user account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you try to host the WCF as it was hosted with the self-host - under an **extensionless** uri.

This won't work. WCF services are hosted under `*.svc` activators. The extension informs IIS that it should find a proper host factory and create the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I solve my problem and get the Hello World example working?

Comment: You need to either add the extensionless uri or add the .svc file and reference it directly.  Search for "File-less Activiation" on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I added the website to the IIS manager and now it is working. I did need to edit permissions to acces the files but now i can acces the page without problems.

Should have read further in the book because they also explain about *.svc activators later.